# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 972: invalid continuation byte: using os, shutil, dictionary to move files

Tags: csv, utf-8, operating-system, shutil

i have a question and i dont know if i can execute it on python
so i have files in the form of cik number-year.txt
and i have created directories of filenames matching firm names
and i have a spreadsheet of filename matching cik

I wrote a piece of code that should perform what I described, but i ran into an error which states UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 972: invalid continuation byte

Here is the csv file that im trying to read

company name ,cik,cik 2 ,missing ,notes 
Deere,315189,,,
H.J. Heinz,46640,1637459,,
Bestfoods,25350,,,
Bayer Corporation,,,,
Sealed Air,1012100,,missing 1994-1997,
Eli Lilly,59478,,,
Campbell Soup,16732,,"missing 96, 97, 98, 99,00, 01",
Honeywell,48305,773840,overlapping years as have honeywell central and honeywell international,
Kellogg,55067,,,
Union Carbide,100790,,"missing 10-ks from 1993-1996, 2001 ",
Cooper Industries,24454,1141982,"missing 1993-2002, 2013-2018",
North American Philips,,,,
Intel,50863,,,
Amerada Hess,4447,,"missing 95, 97, 00",
Martin Marietta,916076,,1994-2002 ,
PPG Industries,79879,,"1997, 2000, 2001",
Litton Industries,59880,,"1995, 2001-2018",
Reynolds Metals,83604,,"95, 96, 97, 98, 00-18",
Warner-Lambert,104669,,"96, 97, 01-18",
Quaker Oats,81371,,,
Levi Strauss,94845,,before 2000,
Northrop Grumman,72945,,2002-2018,
Stone Container,94610,,,
LTV,,,,
American Cyanamid,4829,,,AMERICAN CYANAMID CO merged with American Home Products (AHP) in 1994.
Gillette,41499,,"96-98, 06-18","On October 1, 2005, Procter & Gamble finalized its merger with the Gillette Company."
Johnson Controls,53669,,"97, 98,99, 00, 01, 17-18 ",
Coca-Cola Enterprises,1491675,,"before 2011, after 2016 ",
BASF,,,,
Dana,26780,,95,
Champion International,19150,,nearly no data apart from 95,
Scott Paper,87949,,,The company was acquired by the Kimberly-Clark Corporation in 1995
Lyondell Chemical,842635,1489393,"95-98,09-18","LyondellBasell was formed in December 2007 by the acquisition of Lyondell Chemical Company by Basell Polyolefins for $12.7 billion.[7] As of 2016, Lyondell was the third largest independent chemical manufacturer in the United States.[8]"
Black & Decker,93556,12355,"00,01 ",2010 – Black & Decker merges with Stanley Works to become Stanley Black & Decker
Fort James,53117,,,"In 1997, the Fort Howard Paper Company and the James River Corporation merged to form the Fort James Corporation.[1][4] Fort Howard was headquartered in Green Bay and James River in Richmond,In 2000, the Fort James Corporation was acquired by Georgia-Pacific for $11 billion;[1][4] GP is based in Atlanta, Georgia. Virginia."
Mead,64394,,"missing 2001+, strange. ","missing 2005+, strange. "
Chiquita Brands Intl.,101063,,"98,01,06-18",
Dresser Industries,30099,,,"In 1998, Dresser merged with its main rival Halliburton,[1] Halliburton sold many of former Dresser non ""oil patch"" divisions, retaining the M W Kellogg Engineering and Construction Company and the Dresser oil-patch products and services that complemented Halliburton's energy and natural resource businesses. In 2001 Halliburton sold five separate, but somewhat related former Dresser non ""oil patch"" divisions, to an investment banking firm. Those five operations later took the name ""Dresser Inc."" In October 2010, Dresser Inc., was acquired by General Electric.[2] It is headquartered in Addison, Texas.[3]"
R.R. Donnelley & Sons,29669,,"95,97-02",
Tyson Foods,100493,,"95-99,01",
Compaq Computer,714154,,"96, 97","Struggling to keep up in the price wars against Dell, as well as with a risky acquisition of DEC,[4] Compaq was acquired for US$25 billion by HP in 2002"
J.E. Seagram,,,,Seagram was sold to French conglomerate Vivendi in 2000.
Rhone-Poulenc Rorer,217028,1325676,,In 1999 it merged with Hoechst AG to form Aventis.
Eaton,1490873,,,
Schering-Plough,310158,,"97, 98, 99, 00"," On November 4, 2009 Merck & Co. merged with Schering-Plough with the new company taking the name of Merck & Co."
Bethlehem Steel,11860,,,"After a decline in the American steel industry and other problems leading to the company's bankruptcy in 2001, the Bethlehem Steel Corporation was dissolved and the remaining assets sold to International Steel Group in 2003; Bethlehem Steel Corporation did not merge with/into International Steel Group."
FMC,37785,,"95, 2000,2001 ",
Navistar International,808450,,-,
VF,,,,
Avon Products,8868,,-,
American Standard,836102,,"95-97, 09-19 ",
Ingersoll-Rand,1466258,50485,43532,
Crown Holdings,1219601,,34001,
Cummins,26172,,,
Corning,24741,,1,
OfficeMax,929428,,"only have 97, 02, 03",
Pharmacia,12978,,"95, 96.00.01.02.14-19 ",
Owens-Illinois,812233,812074,,This may refer to OWENS & MINOR INC/VA/ or OWENS ILLINOIS INC /DE/
AMAX,,,,
Times Mirror,98349,925260,95. 99,Times Mirror Co. was acquired by the Tribune Company in 2000
Sun Microsystems,709519,,"95, 00, 01, 10-19","On April 20, 2009, it was announced that Oracle Corporation would acquire Sun for US$7.4 billion. The deal was completed on January 27, 2010.[3]"
Masco,62996,,,
Grumman,1133421,,34001,
Ryerson Tull,790528,1013595,"98-02, 15-18",
Gannett,39899,,,"In 2015, Gannett Co., Inc., spun off its publishing business into a separate publicly traded entity, while retaining the internet media divisions. Immediately following the spin off, the former parent Company (Gannett Co., Inc.) renamed itself Tegna and owns approximately 50 TV stations. The spun-off publishing business renamed itself ""Gannett"""
Pitney Bowes,78814,,"00,02 ",
Farmland Industries,34616,,, sold all of its assets in 2002–04
FINA,,,,
Kerr-McGee,55458,1141185,"95.96.01,07-19",
AMP,1242513,,"before 2009 and after 2014, 2012",
Agway,2852,,only have 94 and 02," On October 1, 2002 the company filed for Chapter 11 bankruptcy"
Air Products & Chem.,2969,,95-00,
Hershey Foods,47111,,,
Varity,63118,,only have 94 and 96,"In March 1999, LucasVarity was purchased by US automotive company TRW.[7]"
Rohm & Haas,84792,,43757, Dow Chemical Company bought Rohm and Haas for $15 billion in 2009
Tyco International,833444,,94-96,"On January 25, 2016, Johnson Controls announced it would merge with Tyco, and all businesses of Tyco and Johnson Controls would be combined under Tyco International plc, to be renamed as Johnson Controls International plc."
Union Camp,100783,,96,In 1999 it was acquired by International Paper.
Harris,202058,,"96, 97,01",
Maytag,63541,,01-02;07-19 ,The Maytag Corporation is an American home and commercial appliance brand owned by Whirlpool Corporation after the April 2006 acquisition of Maytag.
Berkshire Hathaway,109694,,99-2018,
Smurfit-Stone Container,94610,727742,,"SSCC was formed in November 1998, with the merger of Jefferson Smurfit Corporation (JSC) and Stone Container Corporation (Stone).I have also included the Smurfit Corporation cik here "
Universal,102037,,"95,97,98,00,01",
Ethyl,33656,,1,"In 2004, Ethyl Corporation became a subsidiary of NewMarket Corporation (NYSE: NEU)."
Premark International,800575,,missing 00-19 ,
Teledyne,1094285,,missing  before 2002,
Seagate Technology,1137789,354952,,
Loral,1029850,1006269,,
Hercules,1280784,46989,," 2008, when it was merged into Ashland Inc."
Owens Corning,75234,1370946,,
Illinois Tool Works,49826,,,
Hormel Foods,48465,,,
PerkinElmer,31791,77551,,
Paccar,75362,,,
Sherwin-Williams,89800,,,
Pennzoil,77320,,"only have 94, 97, 98 ",
Temple-Inland,731939,,,
Readers Digest Assn.,858558,,,
Mapco,62142,,,
Avery Dennison,8818,,,
Diamond Shamrock,810316,,,
Ultramar Diamond Shamrock,887207,,,
Phelps Dodge,78066,,,
Land OLakes,1032562,,,
AMDAHL,4427,,, been a wholly owned subsidiary of Fujitsu since 1997.
Armstrong Holdings,1109304,,,
Baker Hughes,808362,1701605,,
Hasbro,46080,,,
Goodrich,42542,,,
Ball,9389,,,
Engelhard,352947,,,
Total Petroleum,,,,
Whitman,49573,1084230,,
Olin,74303,,,
Parker Hannifin,76334,,,
National Steel,70578,1231868,,
McDermott,708819,,,
Willamette Industries,107189,,,"In 2002, the lumber and paper company was purchased by competitor Weyerhaeuser of Federal Way, Washington in a hostile buyout and merged into Weyerhaeuser's existing operations."
Becton Dickinson,10795,,,
Westvaco,106498,1159297,,
Knight-Ridder,205520,,,"bought by McClatchy on June 27, 2006"
Quantum Chemical,,,,
Dean Foods,931336,,,
Dover,29905,,,
Intl. Multifoods,51410,,,"*cant find M&A records on wiki, 2005 onwards data missing"
Conner Peripherals,792397,,,"In 1996, Conner Peripherals was acquired by Seagate."
Premcor,1159119,,,Premcor was acquired by Valero in 2005. 
Maxxam,63814,,,
Manville,355473,,,
Brunswick,14930,,,
Collins & Aikman,1037123,846815,,
Stanley Works,93556,,,
Louisiana-Pacific,60519,,,
Polaroid,79326,1227728,," Polaroid Corporation was declared bankrupt in 2001, its brand and assets were sold off. The ""new"" Polaroid formed as a result, and itself declared bankruptcy in 2008, resulting in a further sale and in the present-day Polaroid Corporation"
Tosco,74091,,,"Tosco merged with Phillips Petroleum in 2001. Phillips merged with Conoco in 2002 to become ConocoPhillips, who spun off the Circle K stores to Canadian-based Alimentation Couche-Tard."
Tribune,726513,,,
E-SYSTEMS,,,,"In 1995, Raytheon Company acquired E-Systems, Inc."
ARMCO,7383,,,"In 1999, AK steel holding acquired Armco Inc., its former parent company, for $1.3 billio"
Burlington Industries Equity,870213,,,Its assets were acquired by International Textile Group (ITG) out of bankruptcy in late 2003
Tandem Computers,315180,,,
McGraw-Hill,64040,,,
Springs Industries,93102,,,"On June 27, 2007 Springs said that after 120 years, Springs would end manufacturing in South Carolina with the closing of its Grace and Close plants. The state would still have about 700 employees, most of them at distribution centers in Lancaster and Fort Lawn, and at the Fort Mill offices"
Molson Coors Brewing,24545,,,
Dow Corning,29917,,,"Following the December 11, 2015 announcement that it would merge with DuPont, "
York International,842662,,,"The York brand has been owned since August 2005 by Johnson Controls, when it was sold to them for $3.2 billion."
GenCorp,40888,,,
Asarco,7649,,,"In 1999 it was acquired by Grupo México, which had begun as Asarco's 49%-owned Mexican subsidiary in 1965."
Morton International,1035972,,,
Wang Laboratories,,,,"10-k available online, but somehow not in directory"
Central Soya,,,,
Arvin Industries,7636,,,
Pet,888455,,,missing 10-ks from 2007 onwards
Mattel,63276,,,
MID-AMERICA DAIRYMEN,789868,,,
Sequa,95301,,,
Fruit of the Loom,1053303,,,
Sonoco Products,91767,,,
Dow Jones,29924,,,2007 when an extended takeover battle saw News Corp take control of the company
Rubbermaid,814453,85627,,
Echlin,31348,,,"data available till 1996, no info traceable on internet"
USG,757011,,,
CENEX,823277,,,
New York Times,71691,,,
Shaw Industries,89498,,,"On January 4, 2001, under the guidance of CEO and President W. Norris Little, Sr. and CEO Bob Shaw, Shaw Industries was sold to Berkshire Hathaway Inc."
Witco,107889,,,
National Semiconductor,70530,,,
Imcera Group,,,,https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mallinckrodt
Bausch & Lomb,10427,,,
Clorox,21076,,,
Sundstrand,95395,,,"Hamilton Sanstrand company was formed from the merger of Hamilton Standard and Sundstrand Corporation in 1999. In 2012, Hamilton Sundstrand was merged with Goodrich Corporation to form UTC Aerospace Systems. No evidence of Hamilton Sanstrand can be found in the directory "
Aeroquip-Vickers,59198,,,"On February 1, 1999, Eaton and Aeroquip-Vickers jointly announced that Eaton would acquire all of the outstanding common shares of Aeroquip-Vickers for $58 per share in cash, or approximately $1.7 billion."
Murphy Oil,717423,,,
Metaldyne,745448,1616817,,"Metaldyne Performance Group Inc.'s majority owner, American Securities LLC, and its affiliates acquired HHI Holdings in October 2012; Metaldyne, LLC in December 2012"
Burlington Resources,,,,
Freeport-McMoran,,,,
Cyprus Amax Minerals,,,,
Timken,,,,
National Service Industries,,,,
Harsco,,,,
General Signal,,,,
Nucor,,,,
Duracell International,,,,
Fleetwood Enterprises,,,,
Storage Technology,,,,
Newell Rubbermaid,,,,
Crown Central,,,,
American Greetings,,,,
Cabot,,,,
Lubrizol,,,,
Reliance Electric,,,,
Deluxe,,,,
Advanced Micro Devices,,,,
Lafarge,,,,
WestPoint Stevens,,,,
Great Lakes Chemical,,,,
Bowater,,,,
Nacco Industries,,,,
McCormick,,,,
Furniture Brands Intl.,,,,
Washington Post,,,,
Federal Paper Board,,,,
Hillenbrand Industries,,,,
Del Monte Foods,,,,
Lear,,,,
Joy Global,,,,
Nalco Chemical,,,,
Coltec Industries,,,,
Walter Industries,,,,
M.A. Hanna,,,,
Potlatch,,,,
Thiokol,,,,
Oryx Energy,,,,
Gold Kist Holdings,,,,
Crane,,,,
Wm. Wrigley Jr.,,,,
Great American Mgmt. & Inv.,,,,
Tektronix,,,,
Raychem,,,,
Dresser-Rand,,,,
Gerber Products,,,,
Varian Associates,,,,
Tecumseh Products,,,,
Rohr,,,,

My codes:

```
import csv 
import os 
import shutil
with open('missingfiles1.csv', 'r') as f:
    os.chdir('/Users/lucy/Desktop/summer/datacollection/10-X_C_1993-2000/1994/QTR1')
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    company=()
    for row in reader: 
        company[row[0]]={'cik':row[1]}
        for f in oslistdir(): 
            filename, filetype = os.path.splitext(f)
            fn = filename.split('-')
            if cik==fn[0]: 
            os.path.join('/Users/lucy/Desktop/summer/Summarydatafile',company)
            shutil.move(f,os.path)
os.chdir('/Users/lucy/Desktop/summer/datacollection/missingfiles.csv')
```

Comment: You should put a link to your file. By copying, we lost the original encoding information. The error is clear; your input file is not a UTF-8 file. So: either you decide to ignore the errors, or just try to find the correct encoding (but often there is no one, cvs lines could be in different encoding). In your code there is nothing about encoding, so: which python version? which operating system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue but I am using package pandas.

Import pandas as pd

.
.
.
.
`df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/melissa/Documents/APIlist.csv', header=0, encoding='unicode_escape')`

Adding the 'header=0' and encode the bytes to 'unicode escape' did the trick.