# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 245203: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read in this troublesome file:

annot_path: https://reichdata.hms.harvard.edu/pub/datasets/amh_repo/curated_releases/V50/V50.0/SHARE/public.dir/v50.0_HO_public.anno

this works:

```
anno = pd.read_csv(anno_path, sep='\t', nrows=1862)
```

but there is something wrong after that line, for the life of me I can't figure out how to get past this error when reading any line past 1862:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 245203: invalid continuation byte

What am I missing?

Comment: It was encoded using another codec, probably Latin-1 or some Windows encoding.

Comment: this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57541385/utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xca-in-position-972-invalid-continuation-byte