# Invalid client secrets file, and 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 82: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-development-mode

I have a CSV file saved in my google drive; this file has text data (questions) I want to link with openai to get some justifications, if I ask these questions manually in prompt, i can get answered, but I need all the question answered in one time,

the first approach is the issue with authentication i got the error: Invalid client secrets file ('Error opening file', 'client_secrets.json', 'No such file or directory, 2)

and I tried another approach to read the csv I got the error utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 82: invalid continuation byte

a different approach I tried as below:

```
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth() # This will prompt you to authenticate your Google Drive
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
```

```
import pandas as pd
csvdata=pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/SBISC.csv')
```

```
with open("/content/drive/My Drive/SBISC.csv", 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    text_data = ""
    for row in reader:
        text_data += " ".join(row)
```

Comment: When you get the  `'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 82: invalid continuation byte` error, does that happen when authenticating to Google Drive, or when reading the CSV file?

Comment: The `client_secrets.json` file does not exist in the current directory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 972: invalid continuation byte: using os, shutil, dictionary to move files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57541385/utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xca-in-position-972-invalid-continuation-byte)